# How to use OpenCV to detect a text picture and make the code to stop

Tags: python, selenium, opencv

so my problem is that I have a code that checks multiples generated codes and when the the variant is different it should stop, it's like finding the wining code but I dont know how to make it stop when it founds the wining code. check it out.

Also here's the webpage https://www.kemxtreme.cl.

please im just a beginner, I learned this in 3 days, and excuse me for my bad english, I know, i'm working on it. PLEASE HELP!

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.kemxtreme.cl/ ")

encontrado=False

for i in range (0,50):   #ciclo, cambias el valor y te da mas repeticiones
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='generar']").click()
    time.sleep(0.3)
    cod=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='generado']").get_attribute('value')
    print(cod)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form']/fieldset/input").send_keys(cod)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("// *[ @ id = 'enviar']").click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='principal']/div[2]/div[3]/a").click()
#driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the condition is to find variance between the images you can use opencv functions.

for example

```
GausianBlur -> cv2.subtract(prev_img,current_img) -> make decision
```

If it something with text in image, use [Pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) to extract image and do the logic. 
Example codes to read text from opencv image

```
import cv2

img_cv = cv2.imread(r'/<path_to_image>/digits.png')

# By default OpenCV stores images in BGR format and since pytesseract assumes RGB format,
# we need to convert from BGR to RGB format/mode:
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
# OR
img_rgb = Image.frombytes('RGB', img_cv.shape[:2], img_cv, 'raw', 'BGR', 0, 0)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb))
```

Comment: Could you be able to mail me please (alonzo.gonzalez.dani@gmail.com), I can't understand how to do it, it's getting very difficult. Also if you don't want  to mail me, could you be able to enter to the kemxtrem.cl page and run the code and see how to make it stop when it founds the wining code?, please, I would be so grateful.

Comment: Kemxtreme.cl is the website my bad